# Как спарсить JSON ответ в слабо типизированный контейнер?

Tags: asp.net, json, .net

Здравствуйте. В своем коде я получаю ответ с постороннего сайта в формате JSON.

```
public void LoginzaLogin(string token) {

    string requestURL = LoginzaAuthURL + "?token=" + token;

    WebRequest loginzaRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestURL);
    loginzaRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    WebResponse loginzaResponse = loginzaRequest.GetResponse();

    using(var responseStream = new StreamReader(loginzaResponse.GetResponseStream())){

        string responseObject = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

    }

}
```

Как превратить строку `responseObject`  в обьект, который удобно было бы использовать для получения значений. Насколько я знаю, в старых версиях .net был объект `JsonObject`, который был бы мне очень удобен. Киньте мне наводку. Спасибо!

Comment: Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно просто десериализовать объект,то вам могут быть полезны:

- [Класс DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)
- [Библиотека](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) [Json.NET](http://Json.NET)

Answer (score 2):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string result = client.DownloadString("your url with token");
JObject info = JObject.Parse(result);
```

Вообщем с JObject работать